# Log Table aggregation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2012

I am looking for the best approach to aggregate data in a log. In the table below is a log of "who was on a station". E.g

User1 was on the station1 between "10/2/2014 14:46" and "10/2/2014 14:50"   (2 transactions)

User2 was on the station1 between "10/2/2014 15:00" and "10/2/2014 15:15"(5 transactions)

user3 was on the station1 at 10/3/2014 16:31 (1 transaction)

User2 was again on the same day on the station1 between "10/2/2014 17:04" and "10/2/2014 17:06"(2 transactions)

```html
    Station1  10/2/2014 14:46 User1
Station1  10/2/2014 14:50 User1
Station1  10/2/2014 15:00 User2
Station1  10/2/2014 15:00 User2
Station1  10/2/2014 15:00 User2
Station1  10/2/2014 15:00 User2
Station1  10/2/2014 15:15 User2
Station1  10/2/2014 16:31 User3
Station1  10/2/2014 17:04 User2
Station1  10/2/2014 17:06 User2
```

I am looking for an output like "How long the user was on the station and how many transactions"...Is it possible to do same same without iterating through each item? If so how do I go about it?

```html
station     User    start time        Duration    Transactions
Station1  User1 10/2/2014 14:46   4 min       2
Station1  User2 10/2/2014 15:00   15 min      5
Station1  User3 10/2/2014 16:31               1
Station1  User2 10/2/2014 15:04   2 min       2
```

Comment: I am on SQL Server 2012.

Comment: why there are multiple rows for Station1  10/2/2014 15:00 User2?

Comment: My requirement is to get details of each visit by a user to the station...(only   one user can be at the station in a given time).

Comment: In this case there where 2 visit by user2 on 10/2/2014

Comment: I get that but there are 4 record with the same station, user and time. anyway, I'l close to solve it

Comment: Your result is wrong. in the last record you have User2, 15:04 but User2 has not record with that time. it should be 17:04

Comment: Thanks for look into it...your are right, the time in the result should have been 10/2/2014 17:04....

Comment: also, having the time same is a milliseconds issue

Answer (score 0):

Run these scripts

Script 1

```
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Carlos Aguilar
-- Create date:  April 2016
-- Description:  Massive Creation of Log Tables in a Database
-- =============================================

DECLARE @SCRIPT NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TABLE NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @COLUMNS NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE _LOGS_ CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT NAME FROM SYSOBJECTS WHERE TYPE = 'U' AND NAME NOT LIKE '__LOG_%' 

OPEN _LOGS_



BEGIN TRY

  BEGIN TRAN

  FETCH NEXT FROM _LOGS_ INTO @TABLE

  WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
  BEGIN

    SET @COLUMNS = ''

    SELECT @COLUMNS = @COLUMNS + '[' + T1.NAME + '] ' + T2.NAME + 
        CASE 
            WHEN T1.XTYPE IN (106, 108) THEN
                '(' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, T1.XPREC) + ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, T1.XSCALE) + ')'     
            WHEN T1.XTYPE IN (173, 175, 42, 43, 239, 231, 41, 165, 167) THEN
                '(' + CASE WHEN T1.LENGTH = -1 THEN 'MAX' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, T1.LENGTH ) END  + ')'
            ELSE
                ''
         END
         + ' NULL, '
    FROM SYSOBJECTS T0 
        INNER JOIN SYSCOLUMNS T1 
            ON T0.ID = T1.ID
        INNER JOIN sys.TYPES T2
            ON T1.XTYPE = T2.SYSTEM_TYPE_ID 
    WHERE T0.TYPE = 'U' AND 
        T0.NAME NOT LIKE '__LOG_%' AND
        T0.NAME = @TABLE AND
        T1.XTYPE NOT IN (34, 35, 99) AND
        T2.NAME <> 'sysname'

    SELECT @SCRIPT = 
    'CREATE TABLE __LOG_' + @TABLE + '(' + @COLUMNS + '
        [__DB_USER] nvarchar(128) NULL,
        [__APP_NAME] nvarchar(128) NULL,
        [__HOST_NAME] nvarchar(128) NULL,
        [__IP_ADD] sql_variant NULL,
        [__EVENT] varchar(1) NULL,
        [__TIME] datetime  NULL,
        [__PROTOCOL] sql_variant NULL) '

    PRINT @SCRIPT

    EXEC (@SCRIPT)

    SELECT @SCRIPT = 'DELETE FROM __LOG_' + @TABLE

    PRINT @SCRIPT

    EXEC (@SCRIPT)   

    FETCH NEXT FROM _LOGS_ INTO @TABLE

  END   

  COMMIT

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    ROLLBACK
    PRINT 'ERROR: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE()

END CATCH

CLOSE _LOGS_
DEALLOCATE _LOGS_

GO
```

Script 2

```
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Carlos Aguilar
-- Create date:  April 2016
-- Description:  Massive Creation of Trigger for Log Tables in a Database
-- =============================================

DECLARE @COLUMNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SCRIPT NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TABLE NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE _LOGS_ CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT NAME FROM SYSOBJECTS WHERE TYPE = 'U' AND NAME NOT LIKE '__LOG_%'

OPEN _LOGS_



BEGIN TRY

  BEGIN TRAN

  FETCH NEXT FROM _LOGS_ INTO @TABLE

  WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
  BEGIN

    SET @COLUMNS = ''

    SELECT @COLUMNS = @COLUMNS + '[' + T1.NAME + '], ' 
    FROM SYSOBJECTS T0 
        INNER JOIN SYSCOLUMNS T1 
            ON T0.ID = T1.ID 
    WHERE T0.TYPE = 'U' AND 
        T0.NAME NOT LIKE '__LOG_%' AND
        T0.NAME = @TABLE AND
        T1.XTYPE NOT IN (34, 35, 99)

    SELECT @SCRIPT = 'CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[__LOG_INSERT_' + @TABLE + '] ON [dbo].[' + @TABLE + ']
                WITH ENCRYPTION, EXECUTE AS CALLER
                FOR INSERT
                AS
                BEGIN
                  INSERT INTO __LOG_' + @TABLE + '(' +
                    @COLUMNS + '
                    __DB_USER,
                    __APP_NAME,
                    __HOST_NAME,
                    __IP_ADD,
                    __EVENT,
                    __TIME,
                    __PROTOCOL) 
                  SELECT ' + @COLUMNS + '
                        SUSER_SNAME() AS __DB_USER , 
                        APP_NAME  () AS __APP_NAME,
                        HOST_NAME () AS __HOST_NAME,
                        CONNECTIONPROPERTY(''client_net_address'') __IP_ADD,
                        ''I'' AS __EVENT,
                        GETDATE() AS __TIME,
                        CONNECTIONPROPERTY(''protocol_type'') AS __PROTOCOL
                  FROM INSERTED

                END'

      PRINT @SCRIPT

      EXEC (@SCRIPT)

      SELECT @SCRIPT = 'CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[__LOG_UPDATE_' + @TABLE + '] ON [dbo].[' + @TABLE + ']
                WITH ENCRYPTION, EXECUTE AS CALLER
                FOR UPDATE
                AS
                BEGIN
                  INSERT INTO __LOG_' + @TABLE + '(' +
                    @COLUMNS + '
                    __DB_USER,
                    __APP_NAME,
                    __HOST_NAME,
                    __IP_ADD,
                    __EVENT,
                    __TIME,
                    __PROTOCOL) 
                  SELECT ' + @COLUMNS + '
                        SUSER_SNAME() AS __DB_USER , 
                        APP_NAME  () AS __APP_NAME,
                        HOST_NAME () AS __HOST_NAME,
                        CONNECTIONPROPERTY(''client_net_address'') __IP_ADD,
                        ''U'' AS __EVENT,
                        GETDATE() AS __TIME,
                        CONNECTIONPROPERTY(''protocol_type'') AS __PROTOCOL
                  FROM INSERTED

                END'

      PRINT @SCRIPT

      EXEC (@SCRIPT)

      SELECT @SCRIPT = 'CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[__LOG_DELETE_' + @TABLE + '] ON [dbo].[' + @TABLE + ']
                WITH ENCRYPTION, EXECUTE AS CALLER
                FOR DELETE
                AS
                BEGIN
                  INSERT INTO __LOG_' + @TABLE + '(' +
                    @COLUMNS + '
                    __DB_USER,
                    __APP_NAME,
                    __HOST_NAME,
                    __IP_ADD,
                    __EVENT,
                    __TIME,
                    __PROTOCOL) 
                  SELECT ' + @COLUMNS + '
                        SUSER_SNAME() AS __DB_USER , 
                        APP_NAME  () AS __APP_NAME,
                        HOST_NAME () AS __HOST_NAME,
                        CONNECTIONPROPERTY(''client_net_address'') __IP_ADD,
                        ''D'' AS __EVENT,
                        GETDATE() AS __TIME,
                        CONNECTIONPROPERTY(''protocol_type'') AS __PROTOCOL
                  FROM DELETED

                END'

      PRINT @SCRIPT

      EXEC (@SCRIPT)

    FETCH NEXT FROM _LOGS_ INTO @TABLE

  END   

  COMMIT

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    ROLLBACK
    PRINT 'ERROR: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE()

END CATCH

CLOSE _LOGS_
DEALLOCATE _LOGS_

GO
```

Script 3

```
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Carlos Aguilar
-- Create date:  April 2016
-- =============================================

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SelectLogByDate
(
    @StartDate DATETIME,
    @EndDate DATETIME
)
AS
BEGIN

    CREATE TABLE #TRANSACTIONS
    (
        [TIMESTAMP] DATETIME,
        STATION NVARCHAR(128),
        [USER] NVARCHAR(128)
    )

    DECLARE @TABLE NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @ParmDefinition = N'@StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME'

    DECLARE _LOGS_ CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT NAME FROM SYSOBJECTS WHERE TYPE = 'U' AND NAME LIKE '__LOG_%' 

    OPEN _LOGS_

    BEGIN TRY

        BEGIN TRAN

            FETCH NEXT FROM _LOGS_ INTO @TABLE

            WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
            BEGIN

                SELECT @SQL = 'INSERT INTO #TRANSACTIONS ([TIMESTAMP], STATION, [USER]) SELECT __TIME, __HOST_NAME, __DB_USER FROM ' + 
                    @TABLE + ' ' +
                    'WHERE __TIME BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate'

                EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, @ParmDefinition,
                      @StartDate = @StartDate,
                      @EndDate = @EndDate

                FETCH NEXT FROM _LOGS_ INTO @TABLE
            END
        COMMIT

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

    END CATCH
    CLOSE _LOGS_
    DEALLOCATE _LOGS_

    SELECT STATION, 
            [USER],
            MIN([TIMESTAMP]) AS "START TIME",
            MAX([TIMESTAMP]) AS "END TIME",
            DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN([TIMESTAMP]), MAX([TIMESTAMP])) AS DURATION,
            COUNT(*) AS TRANSACTIONS
     FROM #TRANSACTIONS
     GROUP BY STATION, 
            [USER]

END
GO
```

Wait 1 or 2 days for user transactions and them run

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[SelectLogByDate]
        @StartDate = ?, --Param here
        @EndDate = ? --Param here

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Comment: Thanks for answering the question but, you should not refer to a personal share folder.. Write all your scripts inside the body of your answer instead.

Comment: you should EDIT your question and provide all your scripts in one single post. I think you have posted each script in separate post. Also whenever you want to change your answer, please EDIT your question, do not post a new answer, even your are providing more than one solution, all should be in one post.

Answer (score 0):

**Setup Data:**

```
create table #log (Station varchar(20), Dt datetime, UserName varchar(10))

insert into #log values
('Station1',    '10/2/2014 14:46',  'User1'),
('Station1',    '10/2/2014 14:50',  'User1'),
('Station1',    '10/2/2014 15:00',  'User2'),
('Station1',    '10/2/2014 15:00',  'User2'),
('Station1',    '10/2/2014 15:00',  'User2'),
('Station1',    '10/2/2014 15:00',  'User2'),
('Station1',    '10/2/2014 15:15',  'User2'),
('Station1',    '10/2/2014 16:31',  'User3'),
('Station1',    '10/2/2014 17:04',  'User2'),
('Station1',    '10/2/2014 17:06',  'User2')
```

**Query:**

```
;with TranCount as (
select Station, UserName, count(*) Cnt, MIN(Dt) MinDt
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (partition by Station order by Dt) -
              row_number() over (partition by UserName order by Dt)
             ) as grp
      from #log t
     ) t
group by grp, Station, UserName
)
-- find time from next record. 
-- also number the records to find IN and OUT entries
, cte1 as ( 
      select Station, UserName, Dt
        , LEAD(Dt) over (partition by Station, UserName order by Station, Dt) NextDt
        , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Station, UserName order by Station, Dt) as RN
      from #log
      group by Station, UserName, Dt
)
-- only select IN entries, the exit time will be in NextDt field. 
-- so ignore the even rows.
, cte2 as ( 
      select *
      from cte1
      where RN % 2 = 1
)
select cte2.Station, cte2.UserName, Dt StartTime
    , DATEDIFF(SECOND, Dt, NextDt) / 60 AS Duration, TranCount.Cnt AS TransactionCount
from cte2
    inner join TranCount on TranCount.Station = cte2.Station 
        and TranCount.UserName = cte2.UserName 
        and TranCount.MinDt = cte2.Dt
order by Station, Dt, UserName
```

Result:

```
+----------+----------+-------------------------+----------+------------------+
| Station  | UserName |        StartTime        | Duration | TransactionCount |
+----------+----------+-------------------------+----------+------------------+
| Station1 | User1    | 2014-10-02 14:46:00.000 | 4        |                2 |
| Station1 | User2    | 2014-10-02 15:00:00.000 | 15       |                5 |
| Station1 | User3    | 2014-10-02 16:31:00.000 | NULL     |                1 |
| Station1 | User2    | 2014-10-02 17:04:00.000 | 2        |                2 |
+----------+----------+-------------------------+----------+------------------+
```

*Please "Mark as Answer" if a post has answered the question*